# Hibernate OneToOne mapping reverse Direction?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, mapping

I have two table one is ObjectP and Another AccessObject

```
ObjectP                   AccessObject

ObjectId                 accessObjectId
Name                     groupId
Description              objectId
```

I have applied a one-to-one mapping(which is working fine) in AccessObject as follows:

```
@OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
@JoinColumn(name = "objectId" , insertable = false, updatable = false, nullable = false, unique = true)
private ObjectP objectP;
```

When I access ObjectP I want to navigate related AccessObject too. How can I do that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In AccessObject you'll have the side owning the association:

```
@OneToOne
@JoinColumn(name = "objectId" , nullable = false, unique = true)
private ObjectP objectP;
```

Then in ObjectP you have the inverse side:

```
@OneToOne(mappedBy="objectP")
private AccessObject accessObject
```

- fetch = FetchType.EAGER is the default *-To-One fetch strategy so it's redundant
- the owning side must not have insertable/updatable=false, since you want this side to own the association
- the **mappedBy** is how you mark the inverse side in bi-directional associations

Comment: is it possible to have mapping other way around? Funny thing is that in such case Hibernate correctly generates select queries, but related object is null. I just dont need to have bidirectional relationship.